# como ingresar o utilizar el _id que da por defecto a cada objeto en Mongodb desde React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, react-native, react-hooks

Hola lo que estoy haciendo es una aplicacion MERN de productos donde lo que quiero obtener es el props:_id que crea mongodb por determinado en la base de datos el problema es que no me deja utilizarlo ya que dice que esta indefinido el _id sin embargo cuando lo pruebo en postman si me devuelve el valor _id predeterminado que mongodb creo aqui les dejo la parte del codigo

```
import axios from 'axios';
import CardProductoHome from "../Atoms/CardProductoHome";

const ConjuntoCards = ({ url }) => {
const [data, setData] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url)
        .then(  result => {
            const resp = result
            setData(resp.data)
            console.log(resp.data)
        })
        .catch( err =>{
            let error = err
            console.log(error)
        })
    },[data, url ])

    return(
        <div>
            {
                data ? 
                data.map((props)=>{
                    console.log(props)
                    return(
                        <CardProductoHome 
                            description={props.description}
                            precio={props.price}
                            title={props.title}
                            key={props._id}
                        />
                    )
                })
                : 
                null
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

export default ConjuntoCards;

Este es el tipo de array que me debuelve postamn de mi peticion como digo me da el _id predeterminado pero en react no lo puedo utilizar

```
    {
        "_id": "61ae6d59c303d11da0359ba9",
        "title": "Pulque de Alfalfa",
        "price": 50,
        "description": "Este curado esta hecho son pulque y  Alfalfa se muele y se revuelve para poder hacer todo un barril este es el pulque de Alfalfa",
        "category": {
            "_id": "61aaaddbe729c77b5386b98f",
            "title": "Verduras",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "createdAt": "2021-12-06T20:06:49.819Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-06T20:06:49.819Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "61ae6dcdc303d11da0359bad",
        "title": "Pulque de Anis",
        "price": 50,
        "description": "Este curado esta hecho son pulque y  Anis, lo que hace es que se revuelve y se hace un barril de todo pulque y Anis",
        "category": {
            "_id": "61aaadefe729c77b5386b993",
            "title": "Acidos",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "createdAt": "2021-12-06T20:08:45.062Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-06T20:08:45.062Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "61ae6e41c303d11da0359bb1",
        "title": "Pulque de Apio",
        "price": 50,
        "description": "Este curado esta hecho son pulque y  Apio , sin duda alguna esta hecho esto con Apio y con pulque entre los dos se combian y podemos desarollar este tipo de curado",
        "category": {
            "_id": "61aaaddbe729c77b5386b98f",
            "title": "Verduras",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "createdAt": "2021-12-06T20:10:41.328Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-06T20:10:41.328Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "61ae6f29c303d11da0359bb7",
        "title": "Pulque de Arroz",
        "price": 50,
        "description": "Este curado esta hecho son pulque y  Arroz , por que esta hehco con Arroz , bien fascil esta hehco con arroz para que su sabor pueda ser muy Bueno ya que a algunos nos encanta la agua de arroz",
        "category": {
            "_id": "61aaade6e729c77b5386b991",
            "title": "Cereales",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "createdAt": "2021-12-06T20:14:33.772Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-06T20:14:33.772Z",
        "__v": 0
    }



Necesito el _id por que de ahi a cada objeto tiene otro obejeto donde necesito pasarle ese _id para poder obtener la imagen
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No pudo acceder al valor \_id que da por defecto Mongodb desde React](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/502808/no-pudo-acceder-al-valor-id-que-da-por-defecto-mongodb-desde-react)

Answer (score 1):

En el return le estas pasando por props key, esta es una palabra reservada de React que se utiliza para eliminar el error de los child, mejora la performance.... Si quieres pasar Id, ademas del key={props._id} deberías enviarle ejemplo un productId={props._id} en los parámetros al invocar a CardProductoHome y en CardProductoHome home recibir por props productId.