# No puedo acceder al valor _id que da por defecto Mongodb desde React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native

Tengo un Problema necesito poder utilizar el _id que da por defecto Mongodb para poder obtener una contraseña, Pero lo que pasa es que en el sigueinte codigo en donde ya se obtuvo la informacion del servidor donde esta lista para imprimirse en data.map si me deja ver el id como se puede apreciar lo estoy impirmiendo en  pantalla pero cuando quiero pasarlo como un parametro de un objeto que estoy importando simplemente falla se imprimo el texto que puse en CardProductoHome "No hay key" que puse como prueba, como le puedo hacer para que obtenerlo y lo pueda importar en  esta funcion

```
import axios from 'axios';
import CardProductoHome from "../Atoms/CardProductoHome";

const ConjuntoCards = ({ url }) => {
const [data, setData] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        return axios.get(url)
        .then(  async result => {
            const  resp = await result
            setData(resp.data)
        })
        .catch( err =>{
            let error = err
            console.log(error)
        })
    },[data, url ])

    return(
        <div>
            {
                data ? 
                data.map( (props)=>{
                    const id = props._id
                    console.log(id)
                    return(
                        <CardProductoHome 
                            description={props.description}
                            precio={props.price}
                            title={props.title}
                            key={id}
                        />
                    )
                })
                : 
                null
            }
        </div>
    )
}
export default ConjuntoCards;
```

Este es el codigo del principal Conjunto de Cards en el console.log de id si se imprime el _id Correctamente

Y en esta funcion que estoy importando el key ya no me funciona

````
const CardProductoHome = ({
    precio, 
    title, 
    description, 
    key
}) => {

    return (
        <div id = { key }>
        <div>
            {
                <h1>{ key ? key : "No hay Key" }</h1>
            }
            <h2>{precio}</h2>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>{description}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ShowImage img={key}/>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
export default CardProductoHome; ```
````

Comment: Y repetiste tu pregunta porque???? borra una de las dos por favor...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [como ingresar o utilizar el \_id que da por defecto a cada objeto en Mongodb desde React](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/502801/como-ingresar-o-utilizar-el-id-que-da-por-defecto-a-cada-objeto-en-mongodb-desd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` es una palabra reservada para react, y por tanto no te va a funcionar. Debes usar una alternativa como `keyy` ó `_key`, por ejemplo.

> ## [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)
>
> `Keys` ayuda a React a identificar cual item ha cambiado, ha sido agregado o es removido. `Keys` debe ser pasado a los elementos dentro del arreglo para darles una identificación estable.

Puedes ver más sobre esto en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41934116/4326551)